# Change Title Slide Color in reval.js R Markdown presentation

Tags: css, r, rstudio, r-markdown, reveal.js

I am trying to change the color of the title slide of a reveal.js R Markdown presentation.

I am aware that I should use a custom CSS sheet with the `css: styles.css` option, but I couldn't find any references on how to change the title slide specifically. I am able to change the color of any other slides as [explained here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/revealjs_presentation_format#slide_backgrounds).

Here is a minimal example:

```
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: revealjs::revealjs_presentation
---

# Change Background {data-background=#ff0000}
```

Comment: Always give a minimal example, as it makes it easier for people to help out :) I have edited the question to include one for your future reference

Comment: That's very helpful Michael, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the DOM of the presentation (the HTML structure) you realize, that the backgrounds for the slides are created as individual div elements.
The first one of those defines the background for the title slide:

[image]

Therefore try

```
<style>
.slide-background:first-child {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
</style>
```

This CSS selector picks the element with class `.slide-background` that is the first child of its parent (here the parent is the div element with class `backgrounds`).

[image]

(Notice that if you add the CSS in your RMD directly, an empty slide is produced. Therefore you should include them via the YAML header.)

Comment: Worked like a charm. I should note for people as inexperienced as myself with CSS that the `<style>` tag isn't needed, and indeed it only worked for me when I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this resulted in the color being applied to all level 1 headers, e.g. #

Looking at the DOM I see no way of targeting just the title slide with CSS.

What worked for was adding the following CSS:

```css
/* Set background for all headers 1 # slides */

.slide-background:first-child {
  background-color: orange;
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
}

/* Set background for all headers 1 # slides accept title slide, back to template default */

.slide-background > .present {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: none;
}
```

Though, the transition between header 1 # and 2 ## shows the image / background breefly.